# Finding arbitrary length subsets of elements of a list

Tags: algorithm, recursion, common-lisp, combinations

> **disclaimer:** I'm pretty sure I've managed to muck up something really simple, possibly because I've been poking at this in between
>   "real work" while waiting for some slow C++ builds, so my head's not
>   in the right place.

In looking at
[What's the most efficient way of generating all possible combinations of skyrim (PC Game) potions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449999/whats-the-most-efficient-way-of-generating-all-possible-combinations-of-skyrim) I had the naïve notion that it would be a really, really simple recursive filter in Lisp to generate all combinations of size "n." The answer given there, in R, is elegant and shows off the language well, but that `combn(list,n)` method caught my attention. ( http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/combn.html )

```
(defun combn (list n)
  (cond ((= n 0) nil)
        ((null list) nil)
        ((= n 1) (mapcar #'list list))
        (t (mapcar #'(lambda (subset) (cons (car list) subset))
                   (combn (cdr list) (1- n))))))

(combn '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 3)

((1 2 3) (1 2 4) (1 2 5) (1 2 6) (1 2 7) (1 2 8) (1 2 9))
```

Except, this just returns the first set of combinations … I can't wrap my head around what's wrong, precisely. It seems that the `(= n 1)` case works right, but the `t` case should be doing something differently, such as stripping `(1 2)` off the list and repeating?

So, my attempt to fix it, got nastier:

```
 (defun combn (list n)
  (cond ((= n 0) nil) ((= n 1) (mapcar #'list list))
        ((null list) nil)
        (t (cons (mapcar #'(lambda (subset) (cons (car list) subset))
                         (combn (cdr list) (1- n)))
                 (combn (cdr list) n)))))
```

which is wrong at the point of `(t cons(`… I think. But, if `cons` is the wrong answer, I'm not sure what is right…? (Reduced to using 2 to demonstrate output…)

```
(combn '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 2)
(((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (1 6) (1 7) (1 8) (1 9))
 ((2 3) (2 4) (2 5) (2 6) (2 7) (2 8) (2 9))
 ((3 4) (3 5) (3 6) (3 7) (3 8) (3 9))
 ((4 5) (4 6) (4 7) (4 8) (4 9))
 ((5 6) (5 7) (5 8) (5 9))
 ((6 7) (6 8) (6 9))
 ((7 8) (7 9))
 ((8 9))
  NIL)
```

… which appears to be right, except for the extraneous nesting and the bonus `NIL` at the end. (I had anticipated that `((null list) nil)` would have filtered that out?)

What did I do wrong? :-(

(And, also, is there a standard routine for doing this more efficiently?)

Comment: oh, and `(disassemble)` already reminded me I should use `(zerop)` instead of `(= n 0)`. Yay, optimizing compilers. I'll figure this stuff out, sooner or later :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `cons` is not the right thing, you need an append. And that's also what gets you the `NIL` at the end. I can't write Lisp, so I'll give you Haskell:

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb k (x:xs) = [x:ys | ys <- comb (k-1) xs] ++ comb k xs
comb _ _ = []
```

That's short and sweet, but inefficient (and doesn't check for negative `k`). It will often try to choose more elements than the list has for a long time. To prevent that, one would keep track of how many elements are still available.

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _ = [[]]
comb k xs
  | k < 0     = []
  | k > len   = []
  | k == len  = [xs]
  | otherwise = go len k xs
    where
      len = length xs
      go l j ys
        | j == 1 = map (:[]) ys
        | l == j = [ys]
        | otherwise = case ys of
                        (z:zs) -> [z:ws | ws <- go (l-1) (j-1) zs] ++ go (l-1) j zs
```

Ugly, but efficient.

Comment: d'oh. That'd exactly it. `(t (append (` and the rest is butter. And, just for fun, I changed `((= n 0) nil)` to `((< n 1) nil)`, just for paranoia. Thanks…

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Common Lisp.

Note that this version intentionally uses `assert` to give you a continuable error if the list passed in isn't evenly divisible by the specified number but it'd be easy enough to have it just place any "leftover" items in a shorter list at the end, or use `error` to just make it bail completely without possibility of interactive fixing.

Based on scheme's `srfi-1`, tweaked to CL by me, and improved greatly by Rainer Joswig

```
(defun split-by (list n &aux length)

"splits a list into multiple lists of length n.

Parameters:
  * list - the list to be split
  * n    - the size of the lists it should be broken into.

Returns:
 A list of smaller lists of the specified length (or signals an error).

Examples:
  (split-by '(1 2 3 4) 2)   ; => ((1 2) (3 4))
  (split-by '(1 2 3)   2)   ; => not evenly divisible"

  (assert (zerop (mod (setf length (length list)) n))
      (list)
    "list is not evenly divisible by ~A: ~A" n list)

  (if (plusp length)
      (cons (subseq list 0 n)
            (split-by (subseq list n) n))
    '()))
```

Comment: Don't use EQ to compare numbers. Use EQL or =. See: https://gist.github.com/lispm/c3923a340f90110a1093eeb172302248

Comment: thank you. your version is much better. I've updated the text and incorporated your code.

Comment: I've added two more versions to the gist. Going from simple recursion to tail recursion, to a more efficient and shorter LOOP...